# Unable to set table cell value from Angular controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have written below html and controller code for setting table cell value to geo code address but it is not working.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in tabledata">
    <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
    <td>{{x.lat}}</td>
    <td>{{x.lng}}</td>
    <td ng-if="ctrl.getAddress(x.lat,x.lng)">{{addr}}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller method is as follows.

```
this.getAddress = function(lat,lng) {
        console.log('x.lat ' + lat + ' x.lng ' + lng);
        var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var address;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)}}, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        resolve(results[0].formatted_address);
                    } else {
                        resolve('No results found');
                    }
                } else {
                    reject('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }).then(function(v){
            console.log('Resolved - Geo coder address ' + v);
            $scope.addr = v;
            $scope.apply;
        }).catch(function(v){
            console.log('Catch - Geo coder address ' + v);
        });

        return true;
    };
```

I am getting the address value but it is not getting assigned to addr variable.

Comment: i think it's because addr variable is a local variable of a Promise function. Have you tried putting it as a global variable in the controller?

Comment: address variable is not used in the function. addr is variable in expression in html code and is being referred here through $scope.

Comment: oh! okay. that's why :D you cannot access html variables in the controller without variable declarations. so you have to initialize it first in your controller

Comment: I made a change as <tg ng-init="addr=' ok' " ng-if="ctrl.getAddress(x.lat,x.lng)">{{addr}}</td> so that the variable addr is initialized to empty string. But still in the controller function the value of v is not getting assigned to addr and hence I am unable to see the updated value of addr in the table. It is showing the value as 'ok' but not the address returned by the geocoder.

Comment: did the $scope variable locates the addr?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by locates the addr. I am using WebStorm IDE and when I am typing $scope in the IDE it is giving addr as one of the suggestions. From that context, I feel it is locating addr variable.

Comment: try console.log to log the $scope.addr after assigning the variable v to it. to check if there's a value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138605/discussion-between-satya-narayana-and-chinito).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue as follows.

1) Added one more property called addr to the tabledata in the controller function.

2) After getting the address value from geocode API I am setting its value in the tabledata.